# Nth iteration of $f(x)=x^2+c$???

Tags: functions, fixed-point-iteration

As the question asks (though rather vaguely), what is the nth iteration of $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=x^2+c$? I've attempted to find a solution to this by referring to this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Definitions_in_terms_of_iterated_functions

Specifically, I tried to use the method shown in the section "some formulas for fractional iteration" and that simply got me nowhere, because I'm having trouble with the part where you use the nth derivative of f(x) evaluated at a fixed point.

Then, I tried to find some kind of homeomorphism. If you have the function $f(x)=x^2-2$ which is of the form $f(x)=x^2+c$, you can easily define a function $\phi(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ and show that $f(\phi(x)))=\phi(x^2)$, then do fancy algebra and function stuff to find what $f^n(x)$ is. I was wondering if I could do something similar for the case of any $c$, but I haven't gotten anywhere.

And so I've come here, wondering if anyone could offer some insight for all of this.

Comment: @WillJagy I mean I wasn't expecting it to be "easy", I'm just looking for a solution. However, what you sent me doesn't necessarily answer my question.

Comment: There is simply no formula that works for all $c$; $c=-2$ and $c=0$ are rather special cases. That's partly why this is such an important example in chaos theory.

Comment: Perhaps this is interesting for you - I'm trying to make a good introduction into fractional iteration of functions which have a power series. Of course that can be reduced to polynomials as well. See the first entry on http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/index.htm (http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ContinuousfunctionalIteration.pdf) . I'm thinking whether I should make it even *more* basical with explicte examples for linear and low-order polynomial functions. If you've found something worth say something about it - it helps to reserve time/space to invest in this project...